# Deedle, dropping all but one column

Tags: f#, deedle

In pandas if I want to keep only the target column i can do something like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3), columns=list("abc"))
>>> df[["a"]]
          a
0  0.057213
1  0.162161
2  1.351165
>>> type(res)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Notice that the result is still a dataframe.

However in Deedle if I want to drop all columns but the "a" column, I'm having to do acrobatics:

```
let dropCols = ["b"; "c"]
dropCols |> List.iter (fun i -> someFrame.DropColumn i)
```

Doing `someFrame?a`, gives a series. How do I convert this back to a frame? Is there a straightforward way of keeping only the target column in a Frame while not having it convert to a series?

[EDIT]

In addition to s952163's answer, its worth posting this as well:

```
fr.Columns.[["a"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

`Frame.ofColumns [["a"] => df.["a"]]`

Although in your example above you appear to be mutating the df in place. You can rewrite that to be `dropCols |> List.iter df.DropColumn`, i.e. without the lambda.

**After** looking at the [API docs](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-framemodule.html) it seems there is also this:
`Frame.sliceCols ["a"] df`.